# cache an object once for all users, refresh every 30 minutes

Tags: c#, web-services, caching, web, intranet

I'm working on an intranet and I'd like to cache an object on the server and serve that up to users when requested, as opposed to having each user generate their own copy of the object. I'd also like to refresh the object every 30 minutes...

I'm currently using HttpContext.Current.Cache, but I'm unsure if: 
1. that's what I'm looking for
2. there's a better way to do this (I'm thinking web service)?

Thank you.

Comment: It's a list consisting of potentially hundreds of user objects.

Answer (score 2):

HttpContext.Current.Cache is appDomain wide cache shared between all users. It is appropriate place for your case to store whatever objects you need to share across all users. It also supports expiration.

Comment: So this means when the first user browses to that page, the cache is created, and subsequent users retrieve the object from the cache? If two users do it at the exact same instance, what happens?

Comment: More or less. It depends on your code (see [Add Items to the Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61(v=vs.100).aspx) for details). If you caching objects that is not immutable you need to add your own locking to prevent multiple request to modify your object at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Using `HttpRuntime.Cache` (same as `HttpContext.Cache`) has the pitfall in that it's tied to the `AppDomain`. When that recycles so does your cache.

Instead install something like Membase (Memcache) which acts as an external cache provider and will be persistent between application recycles.

As to refreshing, personally I would cache the item for 30 minutes but allow it to expire. Only refresh it when a request comes in and the item is no longer in the cache. This keeps the cache efficient in that only requested objects remain in the cache.

As a shameless plug I wrote a cache library a while ago that supports Memcache which you can use, see here - http://www.lloydkinsella.net/2012/09/30/bettering-the-better-net-cache/